# Writing the most simple newick parser for Unity3d (c# or Actionscript)

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, parsing, recursion, tree

I am trying to figure out how to read Newick files for many animal species and i haven't been able to find a "logical method / process" to sort the Newick string in a simple programming language. I can read C# and AS and JS and GLSL and HLSL.

I can't find any simple resources, and the wiki article doesn't even talk about recursion. A pseudocode of how to parse newick would be so great and i can't find one.

Does anyone know the fastest way to read a newick file in Unity3d? Can you help to set me on the right track for a logical process to sort through the newick code, i.e:

```
(A,B,(C,D));
```

the branch lengh number is not important for the moment.

target project file:

```
        (
            (
                (
                    (
                        (
                            (
                                Falco_rusticolus:0.846772,
                                Falco_jugger:0.846772
                            ):0.507212,
                            (
                                Falco_cherrug:0.802297,
                                Falco_subniger:0.802297
                            ):0.551687
                        ):0.407358,
                        Falco_biarmicus:1.761342
                    ):1.917030,
                    (
                        Falco_peregrinus:0.411352,
                        Falco_pelegrinoides:0.411352
                    ):3.267020
                ):2.244290,
                Falco_mexicanus:5.922662
            ):1.768128,
                Falco_columbarius:7.69079
        )
```

Comment: I tried to format your code to make it more readable and to show the structure of the tree, from that however it looks like the parenthesis do not match at all. Is this the entire file or just a snippet? Are you sure thsi is a valid newick file? Please verify my edit and make sure that I didn't mess it up.

Comment: Hi, indeed the tree of life example was a snippet of the code, Thanks very much indeed for formatting it. I'll change it a bit so that it's a real tree.

Comment: Hi, updated my original answer with the resulting C# parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing a parser if you have no background in formal grammars might be tough. So the easiest approach seems to be to use a parser generator, such as [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), and then you only need to familiarize yourself with the grammar notation. You can [generate a parser written in C#](http://programming-pages.com/2013/12/14/antlr-4-with-c-and-visual-studio-2012/) from a grammar.

Luckily you can find a newick grammar online: [here](https://github.com/iPlantCollaborativeOpenSource/phyloparser/blob/master/src/main/antlr3/org/iplantc/phyloparser/parser/antlr/Newick.g).

**UPDATE:**

And if you did the above, then you'll get something like the following:

```
public class Branch
{
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public List<Branch> SubBranches { get; set; } = new List<Branch>();
}
public class Leaf : Branch
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Parser
{
    private int currentPosition;
    private string input;

    public Parser(string text)
    {
        input = new string(text.Where(c=>!char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray());
        currentPosition = 0;
    }
    public Branch ParseTree()
    {
        return new Branch { SubBranches = ParseBranchSet() };
    }
    private List<Branch> ParseBranchSet()
    {
        var ret = new List<Branch>();
        ret.Add(ParseBranch());
        while (PeekCharacter() == ',')
        {
            currentPosition++; // ','
            ret.Add(ParseBranch());
        }
        return ret;
    }
    private Branch ParseBranch()
    {
        var tree = ParseSubTree();
        currentPosition++; // ':'
        tree.Length = ParseDouble();
        return tree;
    }
    private Branch ParseSubTree()
    {
        if (char.IsLetter(PeekCharacter()))
        {
            return new Leaf { Name = ParseIdentifier() };
        }

        currentPosition++; // '('
        var branches = ParseBranchSet();
        currentPosition++; // ')'
        return new Branch { SubBranches = branches };
    }        
    private string ParseIdentifier()
    {
        var identifer = "";
        char c;
        while ((c = PeekCharacter()) != 0 && (char.IsLetter(c) || c == '_'))
        {
            identifer += c;
            currentPosition++;
        }
        return identifer;
    }
    private double ParseDouble()
    {
        var num = "";
        char c;
        while((c = PeekCharacter()) != 0 && (char.IsDigit(c) || c == '.'))
        {
            num += c;
            currentPosition++;
        }
        return double.Parse(num, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    private char PeekCharacter()
    {
        if (currentPosition >= input.Length-1)
        {
            return (char)0;
        }
        return input[currentPosition + 1];
    }
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
var tree = new Parser("((A:1, B:2):3, C:4)").ParseTree();
```

BTW the above parser implements the following grammar without any kind of error handling:

```
Tree -> "(" BranchSet ")"   
BranchSet -> Branch ("," Branch)*   
Branch -> Subtree ":" NUM
Subtree -> IDENTIFIER | "(" BranchSet ")"
```

Comment: sorry i was mixed up with the karma. i can start another question and send more karma. I have seen that the parsing grammar is a .g file, it's not ledgible in unity, i don;t know totally what to do. there arent references on .g in unity. thanks very much for the instructions.

Comment: From the .g file, you can generate the .cs file with ANTLR. But it's unnecessary now, just use the C# code from the answer. It parses your input correctly.

Comment: Note that the banch length tokens are optional in the Newick format, a small change to the ParseBranch method will make it support input trees without branch lengths:
`if (PeekCharacter() == ':') // length is optional
        { 
     currentPosition++; // ':'
     tree.Length = ParseDouble();
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Hope you're interested in converting Newick into JSON/Regular object, I think I was able to find a solution.

A quick google gave me links to the implementation on JS:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/biojs-io-newick
https://github.com/daviddao/biojs-io-newick

And, it wasn't hard for me to port JS code into AS3:

```
// The very funciton of converting Newick
function convertNewickToJSON(source:String):Object
{
    var ancestors:Array = [];
    var tree:Object = {};
    var tokens:Array = source.split(/\s*(;|\(|\)|,|:)\s*/);
    var subtree:Object;
    for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
    {
        var token:String = tokens[i];
        switch (token)
        {
            case '(': // new children
                subtree = {};
                tree.children = [subtree];
                ancestors.push(tree);
                tree = subtree;
                break;

            case ',': // another branch
                subtree = {};
                ancestors[ancestors.length-1].children.push(subtree);
                tree = subtree;
                break;

            case ')': // optional name next
                tree = ancestors.pop();
                break;

            case ':': // optional length next
                break;

            default:
                var x = tokens[i-1];
                if (x == ')' || x == '(' || x == ',')
                {
                    tree.name = token;
                } else if (x == ':')
                {
                    tree.branch_length = parseFloat(token);
                }
        }
    }

    return tree;
};

// Util function for parsing an object into a string
function objectToStr(obj:Object, paramsSeparator:String = "", isNeedUseSeparatorForChild:Boolean = false):String
{
    var str:String = "";
    if (isSimpleType(obj))
    {
        str = String(obj);

    }else
    {
        var childSeparator:String = "";
        if (isNeedUseSeparatorForChild)
        {
            childSeparator = paramsSeparator;
        }
        for (var propName:String in obj)
        {
            if (str == "")
            {
                str += "{ ";
            }else
            {
                str += ", ";
            }
            str += propName + ": " + objectToStr(obj[propName], childSeparator) + paramsSeparator;
        }

        str += " }";
    }

    return str;
}

// One more util function
function isSimpleType(obj:Object):Boolean
{
    var isSimple:Boolean = false;
    if (typeof(obj) == "string" || typeof(obj) == "number" || typeof(obj) == "boolean")
    {
        isSimple = true;
    }

    return isSimple;
}

var tempNewickSource:String = "((((((Falco_rusticolus:0.846772,Falco_jugger:0.846772):0.507212,(Falco_cherrug:0.802297,Falco_subniger:0.802297):0.551687):0.407358,Falco_biarmicus:1.761342):1.917030,(Falco_peregrinus:0.411352,Falco_pelegrinoides:0.411352):3.267020):2.244290,Falco_mexicanus:5.922662):1.768128,Falco_columbarius:7.69079)";
var tempNewickJSON:Object = this.convertNewickToJSON(tempNewickSource);
var tempNewickJSONText:String = objectToStr(tempNewickJSON);
trace(tempNewickJSONText);
```

The code above gives the next trace:

```
{ name: , children: { 0: { name: , children: { 0: { name: , children: { 0: { name: , children: { 0: { name: , children: { 0: { name: , children: { 0: { name: Falco_rusticolus, branch_length: 0.846772 }, 1: { name: Falco_jugger, branch_length: 0.846772 } }, branch_length: 0.507212 }, 1: { name: , children: { 0: { name: Falco_cherrug, branch_length: 0.802297 }, 1: { name: Falco_subniger, branch_length: 0.802297 } }, branch_length: 0.551687 } }, branch_length: 0.407358 }, 1: { name: Falco_biarmicus, branch_length: 1.761342 } }, branch_length: 1.91703 }, 1: { name: , children: { 0: { name: Falco_peregrinus, branch_length: 0.411352 }, 1: { name: Falco_pelegrinoides, branch_length: 0.411352 } }, branch_length: 3.26702 } }, branch_length: 2.24429 }, 1: { name: Falco_mexicanus, branch_length: 5.922662 } }, branch_length: 1.768128 }, 1: { name: Falco_columbarius, branch_length: 7.69079 } } }
```

So, this approach gives a way to work with a Newick format as with JSON.

According to the title, you're interested not only in C#, but in AS3 implementation too (I'm not sure that you'll be able to use it in C# right "out-of-the-box", but maybe you will be able to port it to C#).

Comment: Hi Mark, that's awesome information, I need a bit of information about how to access JSON branchsets, what is the JSON quering function to find the childs and parents of any object? Is it faster to retrieve the info's from a Json format file compared to by reading directly from the newick file format as ascii?

Comment: Well, actually JSON doesn't have any specific functions for finding childs/parents. In terms of AS3, JSON object is simple dynamic object and you may implement any search method to work with it. Actually, JSON is a string format for describing regular objects.

Comment: Also, unfortunately, I don't have infromation about performance of working with JSON/Regular objects in comparison to ASII search, sorry =(

Comment: I was wondering, if performance really important for your case? I mean, usually, if you don't have to work with a huge file or win an enormous amount of small/mid files it's not so important which algorythm to use.

Comment: Hi, Oh i thought that you had written both of the answers. So i chose the one that seemed to complete the task. Was in a hurry to find a way round... Unity is very powerful, so a way you can do it is only find the parent of each object, set it as a relation of that object, and use physics to make a branch length to the parent. It will therefore be a ragdoll tree )

Comment: ok probably it is a trivial amount of maths to parse the file, That said, a flexible reading of a big tree can be reading 22mb of text or something. there are big trees around. So if it can be straight away access in arrays or something, i dunno JSON, it figured it may be arrays.

Comment: Well, as far as I understood the code of parser, all **children** properties inside of each "node" is an instance of Array. Maybe it might be helpfull.

Comment: I should say, that 22Mb is pretty big file, so it might be important to improve an algorythm in terms of performance. But I would advice to try the one algorythm that you think is most convinient for your case, and only if you find that performance of it is not appropriate start looking for the another.

Comment: The accepted C# answer can easily be modified to take a `Stream` and not a string as the input. It is only going through the input once, from the beginning to the end, and is only looking at one character at a time. So the file size and the parsing performance should not be an issue there. The internal tree representation can most probably be improved as the `List` is dynamically increases it's size, and after we parsed a given branch we know it's not going to change.

Comment: if i can give karma to both i will try to. ... There is actually a problem with this answer. it doesnt run in Unity3d. I had actually found that code the day before and copy pasted it to unity and had the same error: 
    var ancestors:Array = [];
    var tree:Object = {};
   even those two strings to not compile in unity action script, and line 3 doesn't either. I had tried that code, sorry i thought that you had recoded it

Comment: @ufomorace I think there was a mistake, beacuse my answer got "bounty karma", but I think that the other answer is more convinient for you. Please, could you check it again and send the baunty karma to the right person?

Comment: @ufomorace Also, as I mentioned in my answer, I've used AS3 code and you've mentioned in the topic that you can read AS3, C# and other languages, that's why I thought it wouldn't be hard for you to port my code to C#. The only things you should worry about are: converting AS3 array into the correct types for Unity + C# (Array, List, ArrayList, e.t.c.) + there might be differences in RegExp workflow (which is used in my example).